# Add data in listview using background service

Tags: android, listview

Creating an app in which I am showing feeds in `listview` and storing feeds record in `sqlitedatabase`. Now I want that if anyone add new feed, that `listview` should be automatically update using background service and service will be run in every 1 min and that new value should be inserted in database and generate notification of new added feed.

I don't know how to add service and how to set adapter for listview in service class. I know I have to add intent service for this.
Searched but I did not understood.

What I want: Assume I have two images in feed list view and someone added one more image, so this new added image should be automatically shown in my feed without refreshing the feed listview. For this I have to run background service which will run in every 1 min and that new added image will be shown.

But I don't know how to add service, for this how to call server in service class and add data in listview in service class and add record in sqlitedatabase and generate notification for new feed. This all will be in service class. Extending baseadapter for listview.

Comment: You need an ListAdapter for this

Comment: Yes i have done this but i dont know how to add service and add data in listview in service

Comment: could you be more specific? its also possible to create a inner class which handles your service.

Answer (score 1):

Like i said, you need a ListAdapter which controls your changes and asynchronous stuff.

For example something like this:

```
        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                         "Adapter implementation",
                                         "Simple List View In Android",
                                         "Create List View Android", 
                                         "Android Example", 
                                         "List View Source Code", 
                                         "List View Array Adapter", 
                                         "Android Example List View" 
                                        };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You only need your Service Routine which adds or changes the Array - The adapter will handle your background stuff.

If you use for example the Firebase Database there is a special FirebaseListAdapter which checks deleting, adding, changing the data and will update your list automatically.

For your specific problem with SQLite you should do something like this:

```
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

  // The desired columns to be bound
  String[] columns = new String[] {
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CODE,
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CONTINENT,
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_REGION
  };

  // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
  //as well as the layout information
  dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, R.layout.country_info, 
    cursor, 
    columns, 
    to,
    0);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  // Assign adapter to ListView
  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: The question asked about SQLite and Services. You have not answered with either, why?

Comment: i added the solution for the sqlite also... you need a CursorAdapter for this.

Comment: I  understand all that myself,  but the question was about using a `Service` class to refresh the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BusEvent solution. When your service detect a change you post a new event with the chages. The activity which contains the ListView, will be listen this event and will update the adapter.

You could use a library like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or use a new aproach with RxAndroid and RxJava [RxBus](http://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/).

I think the best option for you is otto because integrate RxAndroid is too much for a simple communication.

A solution with Otto could be:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

BusProvider.java

```
import com.squareup.otto.Bus;
import com.squareup.otto.ThreadEnforcer;

public final class BusProvider {

    private static final Bus BUS = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);

    private BusProvider() {
        // No instances.
    }

    public static Bus getInstance() {
        return BUS;
    }
}
```

ListDataEvent.java

```
public class ListDataEvent {
   List<YourObject> data; ////set your data
}
```

YourActivity.java

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onListDataEvent(ListDataEvent event) {
      //fill your adapter with event.data and update the listView
    }
}
```

Finally the service:

```
public class YourService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        //Gets data and post the event
       BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ListDataEvent(data));
    }
}
```